# Majesty's Fiend vs Michion the Timelord

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend):

> Cannot be Special Summoned. Monster effects cannot be activated.

[Michion the Timelord](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Michion,_the_Timelord):

> Cannot be Special Summoned from the Deck. If you control no monsters,
>   you can Normal Summon this card without Tributing. Cannot be destroyed
>   by battle or card effects. You take no battle damage from attacks
>   involving this card. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card
>   battled: Halve your opponent’s LP. Once per turn, during your Standby
>   Phase: Shuffle this card into the Deck.

**Q1-** Can player A's `Michion` be normal summoned from hand **without tributing** if `Majesty's Fiend` already on player B's field?

**Q2-** If `Michion` battled `Majesty's Fiend`:

- Will `Michion` be destroyed or not?
- Will `Michion`'s owner take battle damage?
- Will `Michion`'s effect of halving LP apply?

**Q3-**: Will `Michion` be shuffled to the deck on standby phase (if both monsters didn't battle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Q1: Yes, Michion can be Normal Summoned from hand.

This is not an activated effect, but a condition on the card itself that grants a summoning procedure. Therefore, Majesty Fiend's effect does not prevent it.

## Q2: No to all three.

Michion's effects which prevent his own destruction and prevent damage from battle are not activated effects, but continuous effects. Therefore, Majesty's Fiend does not prevent their application. The effect of halving the opponent's LP, however, is an activated effect (you can tell by the presence of the colon); it will not be activated at the end of the battle phase due to Majesty's Fiend.

## Q3: No, Michion will remain on the field.

Michion's effect to shuffle itself back into the deck during the standby phase is an activated effect (again, note the colon), and therefore is prevented by Majesty's Fiend.